# How to enable PostGIS in github actions on Windows hosts (no docker)

Tags: github-actions, postgis, postgis-installation

Github workflows on Windows VM offers PostgreSQL, but it does not include PostGIS.  I would like to install it, but it seems it is missing as an installable package.  Is there an easy way to get it installed and used as part of my CI?

Windows Hosts do not allow docker, nor do they allow github workflow services.

P.S. If you know of something similar for the Mac VMs, please comment too! :)

Answer (score 0):

My own solution - it parses Postgis windows download page, downloads and caches Postgis files, installs them into Windows PostgreSQL, starts the service and registers postgis.

```yaml
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: windows-latest
    env:
      CACHED_DOWNLOADS: downloads
    steps:
      - name: Checkout sources
        uses: actions/checkout@v3

      - name: Decide Postgis version
        # Download the list of available Postgis versions, and decide which one to use
        id: postgis-ver
        run: |
          $PG_VERSION = Split-Path $env:PGROOT -Leaf
          $postgis_page = "https://download.osgeo.org/postgis/windows/pg$PG_VERSION"
          echo "Detecting PostGIS version from $postgis_page for PostgreSQL $PG_VERSION"
          $pgis_bundle = (Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $postgis_page -ErrorAction Stop).Links.Where({$_.href -match "^postgis.*zip$"}).href
          if (!$pgis_bundle) {
            Write-Error "Could not find latest PostGIS version in $postgis_page that would match  ^postgis.*zip$  pattern"
            exit 1
          }
          $pgis_bundle = [IO.Path]::ChangeExtension($pgis_bundle, [NullString]::Value)          
          $pgis_bundle_url = "$postgis_page/$pgis_bundle.zip"
          Add-Content $env:GITHUB_OUTPUT "pgis_bundle=$pgis_bundle"
          Add-Content $env:GITHUB_OUTPUT "pgis_bundle_url=$pgis_bundle_url"

      - uses: actions/cache@v3
        id: cache-downloads
        with:
          path: ${{ env.CACHED_DOWNLOADS }}
          key: ${{ runner.os }}-${{ steps.postgis-ver.outputs.pgis_bundle_url }}

      - name: Download Postgis
        if: steps.postgis-ver.outputs.cache-hit != 'true'
        # Download Postgis bundle if not in cache
        env:
          PGIS_BUNDLE: ${{ steps.postgis-ver.outputs.pgis_bundle }}
          PGIS_BUNDLE_URL: ${{ steps.postgis-ver.outputs.pgis_bundle_url }}
        run: |          
          echo "Downloading $env:PGIS_BUNDLE from $env:PGIS_BUNDLE_URL"
          $postgis_zip = "postgis.zip"
          Invoke-WebRequest $env:PGIS_BUNDLE_URL -OutFile $postgis_zip -ErrorAction Stop
          
          echo "Extracting $env:CACHED_DOWNLOADS\$env:PGIS_BUNDLE\*"
          Remove-Item $env:CACHED_DOWNLOADS -Recurse -Force -ErrorAction Ignore
          echo "Expanded $((Expand-Archive $postgis_zip -DestinationPath $env:CACHED_DOWNLOADS -PassThru).count) files from $postgis_zip"
          echo "Moved $((Move-Item -Path "$env:CACHED_DOWNLOADS\$env:PGIS_BUNDLE\*" -Destination $env:CACHED_DOWNLOADS -Force -PassThru).count) files to $env:CACHED_DOWNLOADS"
          Remove-Item $postgis_zip
          if (!(Test-Path "$env:CACHED_DOWNLOADS\*")) {
            Write-Error "Could not find PostGIS files in $env:CACHED_DOWNLOADS"
            exit 1
          }
          
      - name: Install Postgis
        run: |
          if (!(Test-Path "$env:CACHED_DOWNLOADS\*")) {
            Write-Error "Could not find PostGIS files in $env:CACHED_DOWNLOADS"
            exit 1
          }
          echo "Copied $((Copy-Item -Path "$env:CACHED_DOWNLOADS\*" -Destination $env:PGROOT -Force -Recurse -PassThru).count) PostGIS files to $env:PGROOT"
          echo "Starting PostgreSQL and adding postgis extension"
          $env:Path = "$env:PGBIN;" + $env:Path
          & pg_ctl restart -D "$env:PGDATA"
          & pg_isready
          & psql -v ON_ERROR_STOP=1 -c "select version();"
          & psql -v ON_ERROR_STOP=1 -c "CREATE EXTENSION postgis;"
```